# ¿Cómo crear observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Necesito crear un observable que emita un booleano y se pueda cambiar mediante alguna función.

```
mostrar$ = new Observable<boolean>();
```

Necesito que `mostrar$` sea `false` por defecto, y se pueda cambiar su valor desde una función.

```
cambiar() {
  this.mostrar$ = !this.mostrar$;
}
```

Estoy utilizando Angular2 y necesito subscribirme a este observable desde varios componentes.

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

Para resolverlo puedes hacer uso de [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) que es una variante de [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject) el cual recibe un valor inicial y emite su valor actual cada vez que se suscribe

Esto lo puedes tener como un servicio

```js
  import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

  export class AnyService{
      public subject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

      public changeValue(state: boolean): Observable<boolean> {
        subject.next(state)
    }
  }
```

luego en donde quieras obtener el valor accedes al servicio, usas la función para cambiar el valor y finalmente te suscribes

```js
    constructor(private _anyService: AnyService) {}

    public observableFunction(): Observable<boolean> {
      return this._anyService.subject.asObservable();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      /*emite un nuevo valor*/
      this._anyService.changeValue(true);
      
      /*y se suscribe*/
      observableFunction().subscribe(res => {console.log(res)})
    }
```

la consola devolverá `true` que fue el último valor que se emitió antes de suscribirse, la ventaja de este enfoque es que el valor puede ser detectado en cualquier componente que consuma el servicio

Answer (score 0):

Agrego el ejemplo de un observable simple, espero te sirva

```js
//  ejemplo observable simple

//funcion para mostrar u ocultar controles
const ocultarControles=function(valor)
{
 if(valor==true)
 {
  console.log('oculatando controles');
  }
  else
  {
  console.log('mostrando controles');
  }
}

//observable
const obsMostrarOcultar = bandera => Rx.Observable.of(bandera).toPromise().then(x => ocultarControles(x));
// oculta
 obsMostrarOcultar(false);
 
 //muestra
 obsMostrarOcultar(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.1/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un [Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/) es una opción, ya que tienes el control del stream y al mismo tiempo lo puedes tratar como un Objservable.

En la implementacion muestra como puede ser usado:

```js
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Tu subject deberia ser privado, asi proteges su funcionalidad.
const sub = new Subject<boolean>();

// Tu funcion para solicitar el cambio
function mostrarComponentes(mostrar: boolean = true): void {
    sub.next(mostrar);
}

// Tu observable, el cual se puede exponer y extender con otros operadores
function mostrarComponentesObs(): Observable<boolean>{
  return sub.asObservable();
}

mostrarComponentesObs().subscribe(value => console.log(value));
mostrarComponentes();
mostrarComponentes(false);
mostrarComponentes(true);
```

[Miralo funcionando](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-subject-simple-example-pkbycb)